# Parsing Json to iterate through model Flutter

Tags: json, flutter, dart

I am calling an API that returns Json

It successfully returns a jsonString showing the full contents of call as a block.

I then struggled to link it to my `model (TubeRoute)` and then call parts of it, for example, `route.stations`.

I have managed to do something, which means I have to call it like `print(data[2]["stations"]);`

I want to be able to iterate through it like normal json. It is a map containing lists.

Here is the call

```
  Future<TubeRoute?> callLine(line) async {
    var client = http.Client();
    TubeRoute? route; 
    try{
    var response = await client.get(Uri.parse('call'));
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      
   Map<String, dynamic> map = json.decode(response.body);
   List<dynamic> data = map["stations"]; 

// I want to be able to call any list/ part within the model and not just 1 list
 
   print(data[2]["stations"]);

   }
  } catch(e) {

    print("Exception Happened: ${e.toString()}");
  }
  return route;  

  
     }
```

If i use my parse method in a similar APIcall I make I receive this error

```
  Exception Happened: type '(dynamic) => TubeRoute' is not a subtype of type '(String, dynamic) => MapEntry<dynamic, dynamic>' of 'transform'
```

Top part of my model from Quicktype.io

```
TubeRoute tubeRouteFromJson(String str) => TubeRoute.fromJson(json.decode(str));

String tubeRouteToJson(TubeRoute data) => json.encode(data.toJson());

class TubeRoute {
    TubeRoute({
        required this.type,
        required this.lineId,
        required this.lineName,
        required this.direction,
        required this.isOutboundOnly,
        required this.mode,
        required this.lineStrings,
        required this.stations,
        required this.stopPointSequences,
        required this.orderedLineRoutes,
    });

    String? type;
    String? lineId;
    String? lineName;
    String? direction;
    bool? isOutboundOnly;
    Mode? mode;
    List<String>? lineStrings;
    List<Station>? stations;
    List<StopPointSequence>? stopPointSequences;
    List<OrderedLineRoute>? orderedLineRoutes;

    factory TubeRoute.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => TubeRoute(
        type: json["\u0024type"] == null ? null : json["\u0024type"],
        lineId: json["lineId"] == null ? null : json["lineId"],
        lineName: json["lineName"] == null ? null : json["lineName"],
        direction: json["direction"] == null ? null : json["direction"],
        isOutboundOnly: json["isOutboundOnly"] == null ? null : json["isOutboundOnly"],
        mode: json["mode"] == null ? null : modeValues.map![json["mode"]],
        lineStrings: json["lineStrings"] == null ? null : List<String>.from(json["lineStrings"].map((x) => x)),
        stations: json["stations"] == null ? null : List<Station>.from(json["stations"].map((x) => Station.fromJson(x))),
        stopPointSequences: json["stopPointSequences"] == null ? null : List<StopPointSequence>.from(json["stopPointSequences"].map((x) => StopPointSequence.fromJson(x))),
        orderedLineRoutes: json["orderedLineRoutes"] == null ? null : List<OrderedLineRoute>.from(json["orderedLineRoutes"].map((x) => OrderedLineRoute.fromJson(x))),
    );

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "\u0024type": type == null ? null : type,
        "lineId": lineId == null ? null : lineId,
        "lineName": lineName == null ? null : lineName,
        "direction": direction == null ? null : direction,
        "isOutboundOnly": isOutboundOnly == null ? null : isOutboundOnly,
        "mode": mode == null ? null : modeValues.reverse![mode],
        "lineStrings": lineStrings == null ? null : List<dynamic>.from(lineStrings!.map((x) => x)),
        "stations": stations == null ? null : List<dynamic>.from(stations!.map((x) => x.toJson())),
        "stopPointSequences": stopPointSequences == null ? null : List<dynamic>.from(stopPointSequences!.map((x) => x.toJson())),
        "orderedLineRoutes": orderedLineRoutes == null ? null : List<dynamic>.from(orderedLineRoutes!.map((x) => x.toJson())),
    };
}
```

Json example

```
{"$type":"Tfl.Api.Presentation.Entities.RouteSequence, Tfl.Api.Presentation.Entities","lineId":"circle","lineName":"Circle","direction":"outbound","isOutboundOnly":false,"mode":"tube","lineStrings":["[[[-0.225033,51.49339],[-0.226715,51.502005],[-0.226375,51.505579],[-0.22453,51.509669],[-0.217799,51.513389],[-0.210391,51.517449],[-0.201065,51.52111],[-0.188748,51.519113],[-0.178306,51.518187],[-0.167832,51.519858],[-0.15713,51.522883],[-0.144262,51.52384],[-0.135829,51.525604],[-0.123194,51.530663],[-0.104913,51.520252],[-0.097993,51.520275],[-0.088322,51.518176],[-0.083182,51.517372],[-0.075689,51.514246],[-0.076546,51.509971],[-0.085969,51.5107],[-0.090432,51.51151],[-0.094009,51.512117],[-0.103659,51.511581],[-0.11426,51.511006],[-0.122666,51.507058],[-0.124861,51.50132],[-0.133608,51.499544],[-0.143102,51.496359],[-0.156377,51.49227],[-0.174138,51.494094],[-0.182658,51.494316],[-0.192792,51.501055],[-0.196104,51.509128],[-0.187938,51.512284],[-0.175689,51.516581],[-0.167832,51.519858]]]"],"stations":[{"$type":"Tfl.Api.Presentation.Entities.MatchedStop, Tfl.Api.Presentation.Entities","stationId":"940GZZLUALD","icsId":"1000003","topMostParentId":"940GZZLUALD","modes":
```

Comment: Both `List` and `Map` have a `map` method but they have different signature. The first takes an element, the second takes a `MapEntry`. It looks like you are confusing them. Without a JSON snippet and more details it's hard to say more.

Comment: Okay thanks, I haven't had this issue before as all my other calls work with a similar parse method allowing me to iterate in a ```for``` loop. Have updated Q with snippet. Thanks

Comment: Does `tubeRouteFromJson(response.body)` work?

Comment: I receive ```Closure: (String) => TubeRoute from Function 'tubeRouteFromJson': static.``` when trying to print result. Would I be able to use this to iterate and call certain model components? Thanks

Comment: if you can get it to make a `TubeRoute` you could then do `route.stations!.map` or whatever else you want to do to iterate the stations.

Comment: Have got it working, returning the first instance etc. As it isn't a List I can't call ```for()``` to take each example. It won't accept being transferred into a List, should I take tubeRouteFromJson(response.body) as convert to a List? Thanks

Comment: You should be able to `final route = tubeRouteFromJson(response.body);` and `route` should be `TubeRoute`, assuming your JSON snippet is correct. In which case `route.stations!` will be a `List<Station>`, that you can iterate.